# how can sleep() method help other threads to execute, since it holds lock on that object itselt?

Tags: java

I have heared that `sleep(timeInMilliseconds)` method in java holds lock on object and goes to sleep for specified period of time. And I also read that it gives chance to other threads to execute in that sleeping period? How can the `sleep()` method help to other threads if it hols lock on object the other threads wants to use ?

Answer (score 1):

The major difference between `sleep()` and `wait()` is that `wait()` releases the lock or monitor while `sleep()` doesn’t releases any lock or monitor while waiting. Wait is used for inter-thread communication while sleep is used to introduce pause on execution.

`Thread.sleep()` **keeps** the monitors it has acquired (if any).

`Object.wait()` sends the current thread (note that you apply it on the Object) into the “Not Runnable” state, like `Thread.sleep()`, but, again `wait()` is called on an Object, not on a Thread. Since the object is the lock and the thread-object is currently on a "non running state" the lock is released.

Comment: The best answer of the bunch so far. 1+

Comment: Thanks dear. I really got some new things from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the thread has not acquired any lock before sleeping, it wouldn't hold any lock. if it has, then YES, `sleep()` won't give chance to any other thread who is waiting to acquire lock on the object which the sleeping thread has acquired lock on.

So, `sleep()` just puts the thread to sleep for specified time, with all lock it has acquired (if acquired) in locked state.

Comment: perhaps you need some `slowdown` that's why you use `sleep()`.